# split string and remove segments js

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

how can I split these strings so that I get the results below? I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 alert(img/small/Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar_2018.png.replace(/\-/g, ' '));
```

this would alert: Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar
but I need it to work even if the sting has an extra /mid/
I'm pretty sure I will need two replace functions one to get the "Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar" and one to get the "2018"

```
 1. img/small/Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar_2018.png
 2. img/small/Base-Shirt_2016.jpg
 3. img/small/mid/Outside-Pocket-Left_2019.png
 4. img/small/large/Outside-Pocket-Left_2019.png


 1. Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar
    2018

 2. Base-Shirt
    2016

 3. Outside-Pocket-Left
    2019

 4. Outside-Pocket-Left
    2019
```

Thanks!

Comment: take subString not replace

Comment: *"...this would alert: Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar..."* No, not even close. Have you actually tried doing this?

Comment: yep, I know it does not work. Thats why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the two substrings you're looking for with a regular expression:

```
var str = "img/small/Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar_2018.png";
var match = /\/([A-Za-z\-]+)_(\d+)\.$/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    // match[1] has "Closed-Main-Fabric-Collar"
    // match[2] has "2018"
}
```

That regular expression breaks down like this:

- `\/` Match a literal `/`
- `(...)` Capture the text that matches the expression within these parentheses.
- `[A-Za-z\-]+` Match one or more of the characters `A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, and `-`.
- `_` Match a literal `_`.
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `\.` Match a literal `.`.

Since there are two capture groups, they're captured in the resulting match object's `[1]` and `[2]` properties.

Comment: I think that's left up to you, you can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @user2238083: You don't actually need the `png` part, so I've removed it above.

Comment: @user2238083: The above works with the sample data you listed in your question. If you're having trouble applying it to your code, I suggest asking a question posting your code and showing how you're trying to apply it.